# Update datebase by php

Tags: php

I want to update MySQL database by below code, but it doesn't work why?

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("timer");
    $update=$_COOKIE['name'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE user SET password='2' WHERE username=$update");
?>
```

Comment: Its better to use mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements rather than direct input, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String values should be quoted: [**MySQL String Literals**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html).

```
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET password='2' WHERE username='$update'");
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: You will also want to seriously escape your query parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: @maralfarokhinezhad, u should really not use this tho

Comment: See the comment from Quentin below your question

Comment: We propose you some more secure issues. Some guys (not just me) propose you other alternative with PDO. Furthermore, I don't think it resolved your problem because it creates a new one, you are using a deprecated function of PHP...

Answer (score 1):

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=timer;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';

$update=$_COOKIE['name'];

$query = 'UPDATE user SET password='2' WHERE username=(?)';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->prepare( $query )->execute( array($query) );

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Can't be sure if it works because I don't know what you have in your $_COOKIE array.

But the code should look like this.

For security, you can add some text transformation to the variable $update like addslashes or other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared queries, the way you do it isn't a good practice. Check also if `$update` isn't empty, otherwise the query will not work, Finally, use `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("timer");
    $update=$_COOKIE['name'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE ´user´ SET password='2' WHERE username='$update'");
?>
```

Try to mention the name of your table in this query like this: ´user´

Let me recommend you that if your query doesn't work then you could put the whole query in an echo (or print) to see whats wrong.

For example:

```
echo "mysql_query(\"UPDATE user SET password='2' WHERE username=$update\";
```